# How to block storage class pd-extreme for Google Cloud VMs?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, quota

I'd like to block the block storage class `pd-extreme` for Google Cloud VMs for my colleagues in order to avoid it being selected accidentally. We use Google VMs as throw-away testing systems and the class has no purpose for this use case. The costs however shoot through the roof when using it. And let's be honest, "extreme" sounds like something you'd click to try it. I did it...

I tried setting quota for "Extreme PD IOPS" to 0 which seems to stand for unlimited ("Don't make me think, Google!) and 1, but both had no effect (after an hour). It's not the first time that setting quotas didn't work for me - and others apparently. If you convince me that setting quotas is the only solution, I'll contact Google support.

I still want to be able to use storage classes other than pd-extreme.

Answer (score 0):

An organization policy is a configuration of restrictions. As the [organization policy administrator](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/organization-policy/using-constraints#add-org-policy-admin), you can define and set that organization policy on organizations, folders, and projects in order to enforce the restrictions on the specific resource.To define an organization policy, you choose a [constraint](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/organization-policy/understanding-constraints), which is a particular type of restriction against either a Google Cloud service or a group of Google Cloud services. You configure that constraint with your desired restrictions.

For restricting the Extreme persistent disks, you can use [Compute Storage resource use restrictions](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/organization-policy/org-policy-constraints#constraints-for-specific-services) (CE disks,images, and snapshots) constraint (**constraints/compute.storageResourceUseRestrictions**). When using this constraint, users will be restricted to access the resource.Projects, folders, and organizations specified in denied lists must be in the form: under:projects/**PROJECT_ID**, under:folders/**FOLDER_ID**, under:organizations/**ORGANIZATION_ID**.

You can set an organization policy on your organization resource that uses a list constraint to deny access to a particular service. The process is described in the [document](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/organization-policy/using-constraints#enforce_list_constraint) on how to set an organization policy using the gcloud command-line tool. For instructions on how to view and set organization policies using the Cloud Console, see [Creating and Managing Policies.](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/organization-policy/creating-managing-policies)

Comment: That controls usage of who (in terms of the position in the organization tree) can use storage at all. It doesn't allow to block the storage class "PD Extreme" while still allowing all other storage classes for all users, does it?

Comment: You can block any storage class by using that constraint. It is not specific to particular PD's.